# Connection refused on Putty

Tags: windows-7, networking, ssh

I'm currently expierencing some very strange behavior. When I try to contact a ssh server (which hosts some SVN repos), I get "Connection refused".

That goes for 5 to 15 minutes. And somehow after that period it starts working.

The same is happening with my emails, IMAP connection to a different server. Browsing the web and pinging the server works just perfect. Any idea what I can look for? What could cause that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the time on both computers.  Are they the same?  If the time is off, it can break many different types authentication.  It may be that the time is off on your PC and it gets corrected every so often when Windows does a NTP check, only to fall behind again.

Comment: Not many types, just Kerberos (if offset > 15 minutes) and X.509 (if offset > cert_expiry - now). It shouldn't cause the connection to be outright refused, however.

Comment: It seems that you were right. After a windows update ist started working again.